# In what animated movie does a queen accidentally choose a schoolboy she hates to be her knight?

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

Which animated movie is this? A girl who is the queen of her homeland accidentally chooses a boy who she hates as her knight to save her homeland from a monster robot.

The boy is a elementary or maybe middle school kid. The queen only takes admission in his school to choose her class' most popular guy as the knight, but accidentally chooses him. The robot kind of looks like Zurg from Toy Story.

Comment: Was this Western or Japanese animation? Was it aimed at children, teens or adults? Where and when did you watch it? What language did you watch it in? Are you certain it was a movie rather than a TV show?

Comment: Sounds like an anime.